Does the hard shell of a chicken egg come from the genetics of the chick or of the mother?
Brought to you by my "what came first, the chicken or the egg?" debate with my elementary aged children.
What causes a chicken egg to develop a hard shell? Does the zygote/embryo create this hard shell, or does the mother's body apply it to the developing chick? In other words, does the hard-shell genotype manifest as a phenotype on the hen or on the egg?
Our hypothetical way to test this hypothesis was, "What would happen if you transplant an egg from a soft-shelled species, say a turtle, into the uterus of a chicken? Would it develop a hard shell?"

A chicken's reproductive system consists of two parts: the ovary and oviduct.

All of the other parts of the egg are added to the yolk as it passes through the oviduct. The chalazae, albumen, shell membranes, and shell are formed around the yolk to make the complete egg, which is then laid. This complete cycle usually requires a little more than 24 hours. About 30 minutes after the egg is laid, another yolk is released and the process repeats itself.

The part of the oviduct that lays down the hard shell is called the uterus, a.k.a. the shell gland.
For an embryo to be present, a chicken's egg needs to be fertilized; a rooster needs to have done his part. Otherwise, there is no embryo, just the mother's genetic material (the egg). This is overwhelmingly the case with store bought eggs; roosters are unnecessary if only eggs are desired. In that case, they're just another mouth to feed (a noisy and disruptive one to boot, but often handsome as all get-out.) Yet unfertilized eggs (containing only the mother's DNA) have a shell.
To test your hypothesis, no transplant is necessary. You could change that to, "What would happen if you transplanted an unfertilized egg into the uterus of a chicken?" Which is, of course, the vast majority of commercial eggs. The shell making "machinery" is all in the mother.
I had chickens, lots of them. I was not willing to kill the young roosters simply because they were male, which meant that I also had an unheard of number of roosters. Well, they weren't exactly unheard. They were incredibly noisy, and if too aggressive, they were the first to become part of a meal. Bless my patient (but not nearby) neighbors!
